# Wrong result code after onActivityResult() to enable bluetooth and discovery

Tags: android, bluetooth, onactivityresult

I have an activity where I ask to enable Bluetooth and discovery mode. 
Requests are executed correctly and are taken by `onactivityresult()`.
The problem is in the discovery request.

If I click on reject then `RESULT_CANCELED` is taken correctly, while if I click on allow, the result code is 120 and therefore it is not `RESULT_OK` and I cannot start the activity, it is normal that it is 120 and not `RESULT_OK`?

**MyActivity**

```
public class TransitionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int ENABLE_REQUEST = 0;
    private static final int DISCOVER_REQUEST = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transition);

        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(bluetoothAdapter == null){ //bluetooth not supported
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

        if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            Intent i = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(i,ENABLE_REQUEST);

        }
        if(!bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
            Intent i = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            startActivityForResult(i,DISCOVER_REQUEST);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == ENABLE_REQUEST){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            }
            if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                Toast.makeText(this, "You need to enable the bluetooth.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
        if(requestCode == DISCOVER_REQUEST){
            System.out.println("RESULT CODE" + resultCode); //it is 120
            if(resultCode ==  RESULT_OK){ //skipped
                Intent secondActivity = new Intent(this, com.project.secondActivity.class);
                this.startActivity(secondActivity);
            }
            if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value of resultCode is same as discoverable duration `EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION` passed in Intent.
and by default duration is 120. So it is OK.

If you will start activity like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
i.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 240);
startActivityForResult(i,DISCOVER_REQUEST);
```

It will return 240 as result code.